# FreeBSD sed in shell script: command a expects \ followed by text

Tags: shell, sed, escaping, freebsd

I write script to create web host on my develop computer.
It has to create directory for host and change nginx config file.
When I try to add strings using double quote to config file sed generate error:

```
#!/bin/sh

webdir="/var/chroot/www"
destdir="${webdir}/$1"
nginxconfig="/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"

sed "/hostsection/ a\
\
  server {\
    listen 80;\
    server_name $1 www.$1;\
    root  ${destdir}/www;\
    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/yii-rewrite.conf;\
    access_log ${destdir}/access_log main;\
    error_log ${destdir}/error_log error;\
  }\
\
" ${nginxconfig}
```

Error looks like this:

```
sed: 1: "/hostsection/ a  server ...": command a expects \ followed by text
```

If I try to use single quote

```
....
sed '/hostsection/ a\
...
' ${nginxconfig}
```

sed works fine but it don't replace variable in strings and trim spaces on begin each string:

```
#  hostsection

server {
listen 80;
server_name $1 www.$1;
root  ${destdir}/www;
include /usr/local/etc/nginx/yii-rewrite.conf;
access_log ${destdir}/access_log main;
error_log ${destdir}/error_log error;
error_page 413 /413.html;
}
```

How I can correct my script to eliminate sed error in double quotes case?

How I can add spaces on begin strings?

Comment: what version of sed are you using? "sed --version"

Comment: @Victor..ok gotcha "freebsd"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslash will [escape](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_02_01) the newline character so sed sees it all as one single long line.

Use double backslash at the end of the lines to avoid this. Then you can use a single backslash to escape the leading whitespace.

```
sed "/hostsection/ a\\
\\
\  server {\\
\    listen 80;\\
\    server_name $1 www.$1;\\
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed

```
Multibyte characters containing a byte with value 0x5C (ASCII `\')  may be
     incorrectly treated as line continuation characters in arguments to the
     ``a'', ``c'' and ``i'' commands.  Multibyte characters cannot be used as
     delimiters with the ``s'' and ``y'' commands.
```

You double quote  your sed command so that your shell can substitute the variable, but then shells such as bash interprets the "\" as a line continuation character at **the end of a line**.

Possible Solution 
Use `\\` instead of `\` **at the end of each line**. this way bash will interpret the literal backslash and sed will understand the literal backslash as a new-line character.